# How do you export a Google Sheet to PDF with Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, export-to-pdf, gspread

I am using [Gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread), but they have deprecated the export method. Any alternatives?

Ideally, I would like to output a download link to my user. Keep in mind that I already tried to just grab the generic download link and output that, but that is no good, since this sheet is going to be changing a lot.

Comment: Have you tried Google app script with the mail too method? You can use that to send pdfs of your spreadsheets a quick search will give you a plethora of answers

Comment: Can you call the google app script from Python?

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea, but Google app script uses javascript and you deploy the scripts from within the Google app script editor Check out https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: If authenticated, you can use the Apps Script API to call Apps Script methods from 3rd party code. Otherwise, you would use the Drive API to perform generic file manipulations (such as exporting to arbitrary filetypes).